# Is the manpage of qsort(3) right?

Tags: c, qsort

The manpage of the `qsort(3)` library routine gives an example of sorting the words given as arguments on the command-line. The comparison function reads as follows:

```
static int
       cmpstringp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
       {
           /* The actual arguments to this function are "pointers to
              pointers to char", but strcmp(3) arguments are "pointers
              to char", hence the following cast plus dereference */

           return strcmp(* (char * const *) p1, * (char * const *) p2);
       }
```

But what's being sorted here are the elements of `argv`. Now `argv` is a pointer to pointers of chars, which can be viewed also as a table of pointers to chars.

Hence its elements are pointers to chars, so shouldn't the actual arguments of `cmpstringp` be pointers to chars, and not "pointers to pointers to char"?

Comment: If you were sorting an array of ints, would you then be expecting to cast the `const void* p1` to an `int`, rather than to a `const int*`? What about an array of 10KB structs, where the elements are much larger that void* could possibly be?

Comment: While working from that code to understand what is going on is perfectly reasonable, you might want to reconsider the title of your question. I mean, do you realize how *long* that manpage and code have been in existence? How *many* eyeballs have taken them in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The callback function passed as argument to `qsort()` is called with, as arguments, *pointers to* the two values to compare. If you sort an array of `char *` (e.g. `argv[]`) then the values are `char *` (pointers to `char`) and the comparison function will receive pointers to such values, i.e. pointers to pointers to `char`.

Answer (score 2):

```
strcmp(* (char * const *) p1, * (char * const *) p2)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So `p1` is of type `* (char * const *)` or, by removing *'s `(char * const)`; and `char *const` is assignment compatible with `char *`, so no problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

No, because presumably you would call `qsort` as follows:

```
qsort(&argv[0], argc, sizeof(char*), cmpstringp);
```

i.e. you pass it a pointer-to-element, and an element is a `const char *`.